# How to apply onehot encoder over vectorized dataframe columns?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

Suppose that we have this data frame:

| ID | CATEGORIES |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ['A'] |
| 1 | ['A', 'C'] |
| 2 | ['B', 'C'] |

And I want to apply one hot encoder to categories column. The result I want is

| ID | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I know it can be easily codded. I just want to know if this function is already implemented in some package. Code it in python will probably result in a quite slow function.

(i needed to put the tables in code fields because stackoverflow was not allowing me to post it as tables)

Comment: Rather than suggesting a library such as [sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), try using it and if you do not get the desired output edit the question.

Comment: Please refer following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74015943/split-pandas-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns-based-on-value/74016030#74016030

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) combined with [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
out = df[['ID']].join(df['CATEGORIES'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies())
```

Output:

```
   ID  A  B  C
0   0  1  0  0
1   1  1  0  1
2   2  0  1  1
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [0, 1, 2],
                   'CATEGORIES': [['A'], ['A', 'C'], ['B', 'C']]})
```

There are many other alternatives, using `pivot`, `crosstab`, etc.

One example:

```
df2 = df.explode('CATEGORIES')

out = pd.crosstab(df2['ID'], df2['CATEGORIES']).reset_index()
```